# Problem with fancyhdr: chapter name not displayed correctly with leftheader

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr

Good evening,
It's the first time that I ask a question on the stack website so don't hesitate to tell me if I do something wrong.

My problem:
-I'm writing a master thesis with the report class and I would like to display in the left part of the header the chapter name and also the number of the chapter like "Chapitre1.NameOfChapter". By looking on the internet I've found a nice way to do it but it doesn't work for all the pages. A weird thing happens when I write more than one section in the same chapter: the header displays only "Chapter1." But not the name of the chapter anymore.
Here is a small working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[L]{\chaptermark \slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{MyName}}
\lfoot{\today}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}

\clearpage
\section{test1}

\clearpage
\section{Test2} %don't display anymore chapter name!!

\end{document}
```

Do you have an idea of what is wrong in the way I use the fancyhdr package?

Comment: Why  `\chaptermark`?   you need just  `\fancyhead[L]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}`

Comment: does something like this `\fancyhead[RO,LE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}` solves the problem?

Comment: @salimbou : you're totally right. I've tested and it seems that removing the \chaptermark solves totally my problem. Thank you! Maybe you can post as an answer sothat I can validate it!

Comment: @Yorgos : your answer works also but seems more complex so I think that the one from salim is better. But anyway thank you to have taken the time to answer also^^.

Comment: @SalimBou would you like to write an answer or do we find a duplicat?